# Euclidean GCD function returns type None instead of int

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, math

I'm getting back into mathematics, algorithms, and data structures. Today, I spent time studying up on the Euclidean algorithm and greatest common divisors.

Below, I implemented a function to demonstrate what I learned:

```
from math import floor

def euclidian(a: int, b: int):
    # a = b * q + r
    _q: int = int(floor(a / b))
    print(f"Quotient: {_q}")
    r: int = a % b
    print(f"Remainder: {r}")
    a = b
    print(f"A = B({a})")
    b = r
    print(f"B = R({b})")

    if a != 0 and b != 0:
        euclidian(a, b)

    # a = 0; gcd(0, b) = b
    elif a == 0:
        print(f"Returning value a({b}) | type: {type(b)}")
        return b

    # b = 0; gcd(a, 0) = a 
    elif b == 0:
        print(f"Returning value a({a}) | type: {type(a)}")
        return a

a: int = 270
b: int = 192
gcd: int = euclidian(a, b)
print(f"GCD type: {type(gcd)}")
print(f"GCD({a}, {b}) = {gcd}")
```

This recursive function goes through a couple iterations, and ends up returning these results:

```
Quotient: 6
Remainder: 0
A = B(6)
B = R(0)
Returning value a(6) | type: <class 'int'>

GCD type: <class 'NoneType'>
GCD(270, 192) = None
```

It's getting later in the day, so perhaps I just need a cup of tea to wake myself up. But I can't seem to wrap my head around why the variable `gcd` is `None` and not the integer value of `a`. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You have `if`/`elif`/`elif` at the end of your function, but not all of them `return`. If your code takes the first branch then it reaches the end, and there is no explicit `return` statement so it returns `None`.

Comment: Thanks guys. The book I'm reading, Grokking Algorithms, didn't include a return statement when calling its recursive function in one example. I didn't think about that. I refactored the code to include a base case as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a recursive call but not returning the value. i.e.

```
if a != 0 and b != 0:
    euclidian(a, b)
```

should be

```
if a != 0 and b != 0:
    return euclidian(a, b)
```

You also have no base case as others have said.

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns `None`, it usually means it ran off the end of the code without hitting a `return` statement.  In your case you have a bunch of `if` statements, and I'm guessing none of them applied.